# type missmatch in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

In my test code, I have

```
var rdd = h5read()
rdd=rdd.map(x => f(x._1,x._2))
```

f is defined as

```
def f(v:Double, k:Int):(Int,Double)={}
```

h5read is defined as

```
def h5read():RDD[(Double,Int)]{}
```

When I run sbt assembly, why I got this error:

```
[error]  found   : (Int, Double)
[error]  required: (Double, Int)
[error]  rdd=rdd.map(x => f(x._1,x._2))
```

Answer (score 0):

- `rdd`'s type is inferred to be `RDD[(Double, Int)]`, due to `h5read`'s return type
- when you call `rdd=rdd.map(f)`, `f` must have the type `(Double, Int) => (Double ,Int)`, because `map` is called on an `RDD[(Double, Int)]` and must **return** a `RDD[(Double, Int)]`, because you're re-assigning it into `rdd`.
- Since you want `f` to return a different type, you can't re-assign it into the same `rdd` variable

To fix this - don't update `rdd`, create a new `var` (or better yet - *use `val`s and not `var`s!*):

```
val rdd = h5read()
val rdd2 = rdd.map(x => f(x._1,x._2))
```

If you really want to re-use `rdd`, you'd have to give it a less-specific type, **but this isn't a good practice** (mutable variables and loosely-typed values are both a source of problems, like the one you're seeing):

```
// bad option:
val rdd: RDD[(AnyVal, AnyVal)] = h5read()
rdd = rdd.map(x => f(x._1,x._2))
```

Comment: Thanks, does it mean, I can do like:
rdd = h5read().map(x => f(x._1,x._2))